# Is there a way to obtain multiple values of a slot in an array format?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I have developed a custom alexa skill. There I have a product search intent which has a slot type called brand. 
When a user searches for something like "I want Nike and Andrew Geller shoes" (both Nike and Andrew Geller are brands) the slot value is identified as "Nike Andrew Geller".

Is there a possibility to identify these 2 brands as elements of an array? i.e: [Nike, Andrew Geller].

The reason is I have an API call to perform with these identified brands where the query I have to make is like `Brand:Nike+Brand:Andrew Geller`. But when the slot value is "Nike Andrew Geller" I don't know whether it's a brand, 2 brands or 3 bands to make the above API query.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to chain slots. For instance

{slotone}

{slotone} {slottwo}

However without a clear separator between the slots recognition might be poor.

So for your example if you know there would be 1 to 3 count of slots

{countone}{slotone}

{countone}{slotone} and {counttwo}{slottwo} and {countthree}{slotthree}

Comment: This seems not a positive answer. Because I can't add any separators to a training utterance of an intent of Alxea skill. Other thing is I already have `{brandslot}`, `{brandslot} {brandslot}` and `{brandslot} {brandslot} {brandslot}` utterances. Still the identified brands value is a string. As long as its a string I cannot separate the values.

Comment: Did you try using different slot variables? ex. {BrandSlotOne} {BrandSlotTwo} {BrandSlotThree} ? My understanding is, If you use just {BrandSlot}, your slot value will just be the last value from the input.